# Maven install fails with type=pom dependency

Tags: java, maven

I'm updating a maven dependency `tika-parsers` from v1.14 to v2.4.0. Changing the version alone causes maven to fail to find the jar:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project samm:samm:war:2.0.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:jar:2.4.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

Since [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers/2.4.0) reports that v2 now needs to have `<type>pom</type>`, I added that in and while the jar error goes away, my code fails to compile as it can't find anything in the tika-parses package.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

`package org.apache.tika.detect does not exist`

I've confirmed that the package should exist as it hasn't been renamed in v2, it's still in their API docs. It sounds like type=pom should tell maven to download all of the dependencies listed in *their* POM but I can't tell what's happening.

Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the pom you’ve linked you can see it lists 0 compile time dependencies, and the core library is listed as a unit test scope dependency.
If you follow the getting started, it seems that you’re supposed to depend on tika-core as well: https://tika.apache.org/2.4.0/gettingstarted.html

Comment: This answer, combined with the other for `tika-parsers-standard-package` appear to solve my issues. The TIKA changelogs did a very poor job of explaining this change. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers-standard-package/2.4.0. It's not as complete as version 1.x, but there are others in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika.